# How does one install wxmaxima?

Tags: macos, macports, maxima, gcc5, wxmaxima

I entered
sudo port install maxima
and got
Error: Failed to build libgcc-devel: command execution failed
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_gcc10/libgcc-devel/main.log for details.
Error: rev-upgrade failed: Error rebuilding gcc5
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
--->  Some of the ports you installed have notes:
  wget has the following notes:
    To customize wget, you can copy /opt/local/etc/wgetrc.sample to
    /opt/local/etc/wgetrc and then make changes.

Comment: Please format your question and, most importantly, define a question!

Answer (score 1):

I work with MacOS at the office and I've had good luck with the [Homebrew package management system](https://brew.sh/). Looks like Homebrew has a formula for wxMaxima, see: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/wxmaxima

That description doesn't mention Maxima as a dependency, which makes me think that you'll need to install Maxima first. Also, I remember that when I installed Maxima via Homebrew, the Maxima formula didn't name SBCL (the Lisp implementation for compiling Maxima) as a dependency, so I had to install that before Maxima. So, without trying it, my suggestion is to try:

```
$ brew install sbcl
$ brew install maxima
$ brew install wxmaxima
```

There are some notes about post-installation configuration on the Homebrew page I linked which you can take a look at.

Homebrew is a great system for installing all kinds of software, so it's useful in many ways, I recommend it highly.